# Is it possible to add extra fields or custom fields to android calendar to manage?

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am doing some trial on `android calendars`. Apart from the `fields/columns` provided by `calendar provider API` as tables(events, remainders, instances). If we needs to handle extra fields like `event type` etc etc corresponding to `calendars` and the events what would be the best way to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here: https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/elements?hl=fr#gdExtendedProperty

Just happened upon your post and thought this might help.

Comment: We can use extended properties available with CalendarContract.ExtendedProperties (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.ExtendedProperties.html) but these are accessible only by SyncAdapters which is not ideal for normal usage and is used only for server sync.. so i had to use SQLlite local db for my application.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can use extended properties available with CalendarContract.ExtendedProperties (developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/…) but these are accessible only by SyncAdapters which is not ideal for normal usage and is used only for server sync.. so i had to use SQLlite local db for my application.. thanks –